# Problems with DI in custom controller

Tags: magento2, extensions, controllers

I am creating an extension which will add a product to cart based on an url parameter (https://unavio.de/shop/ExAddtoCart?sku=2889). Code is running correct as long as I am not injecting any dependency other than:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
```

So here is my (working) Index.php:

```
<?php
namespace Unavio\ExternalAddToCart\Controller\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/AddToCart.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("######### Start AddToCart call #########");
        $logger->info("Checking for URL-parameter");
        if (count($_GET) && isset($_GET['sku'])) {
            $sku = $_GET['sku'];
            $logger->info($sku);
            $params = array();
            $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity

            ### Code should continue here :-)
        }else {
            $logger->info("No or invalidURL-parameter");
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('catalog/');
        } 
      }
    }
```

I am trying to follow this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968822/add-product-to-cart-programatically-magento2

But as soon as I inject

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
```

like this:

```
<?php
namespace Unavio\ExternalAddToCart\Controller\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
protected $cart;
protected $product;
protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/AddToCart.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("######### Start AddToCart call #########");
    $logger->info("Checking for URL-parameter");
    if (count($_GET) && isset($_GET['sku'])) {
        $sku = $_GET['sku'];
        $logger->info($sku);
        $params = array();
        $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
        $_product = $this->product->load($pId);
            if ($_product) {
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                $this->cart->save();
             }
        ### Code should continue here :-)
    }else {
        $logger->info("No or invalidURL-parameter");
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('catalog/');
    } 
  }
}
```

I am just getting a white page and no logging.
Any ideas what´s wrong with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you delete these 2 lines 
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart; and run di compile and test again.

Comment: After di complie code is running again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use your all dependencies between context and resultPageFactory.

And second use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory instead product model directly. Because some extension may have added plugins and presences over this model.

And I can see there is an undefined variable `$pId` at this line `$_product = $this->product->load($pId);`

Also enable display error and error reporting on in file app/bootstrap.php at very first section in file.

Comment: 1. undefined variable => copy/paste error
2. moved dependencies
3. I will try to switch to ProductFactory. 

I´ll post my results

Comment: When you will use productFactory the you need to call $product->create () before calling any product model function.

Comment: Did it like this: $_product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id); seems to work. Also switched to productID instead of sku

Comment: If this solved your problem then please mark this as correct solution and upvote as well

Answer (score 0):

Delete  these 2 lines:

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product; 
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
```

and then run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and test again.